# How to build a new Rust project with Serde crate (v.1.0.189) as dependency

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, serde, rust-crates

I'm trying to develop a simple feature in a new Rust project and every time that I add the serde crate (https://crates.io/crates/serde) my build stops working. Not sure why. At the bottom of the command there is a "No such file or directory (os error 2)" message. But that is a clean install using rustup. Can that be related?

That's the output:

```
$ cargo build -vv
   Dirty proc-macro2 v1.0.69: stale, unknown reason
   Compiling proc-macro2 v1.0.69
       Fresh unicode-ident v1.0.12
     Running `CARGO=/home/rodrigosilva/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/cargo CARGO_CRATE_NAME=build_script_build CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR=/home/rodrigosilva/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/proc-macro2-1.0.69 CARGO_PKG_AUTHORS='David Tolnay <dtolnay@gmail.com>:Alex Crichton <alex@alexcrichton.com>' CARGO_PKG_DESCRIPTION='A substitute implementation of the compiler'\''s `proc_macro` API to decouple token-based libraries from the procedural macro use case.' CARGO_PKG_HOMEPAGE='' CARGO_PKG_LICENSE='MIT OR Apache-2.0' CARGO_PKG_LICENSE_FILE='' CARGO_PKG_NAME=proc-macro2 CARGO_PKG_README=README.md CARGO_PKG_REPOSITORY='https://github.com/dtolnay/proc-macro2' CARGO_PKG_RUST_VERSION=1.56 CARGO_PKG_VERSION=1.0.69 CARGO_PKG_VERSION_MAJOR=1 CARGO_PKG_VERSION_MINOR=0 CARGO_PKG_VERSION_PATCH=69 CARGO_PKG_VERSION_PRE='' LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/home/rodrigosilva/git/serde-test/target/debug/deps:/home/rodrigosilva/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib:/home/rodrigosilva/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib' /home/rodrigosilva/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/rustc --crate-name build_script_build --edition=2021 /home/rodrigosilva/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/proc-macro2-1.0.69/build.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts,future-incompat --diagnostic-width=213 --crate-type bin --emit=dep-info,link -C embed-bitcode=no --cfg 'feature="default"' --cfg 'feature="proc-macro"' -C metadata=984fd110d6c25c2b -C extra-filename=-984fd110d6c25c2b --out-dir /home/rodrigosilva/git/serde-test/target/debug/build/proc-macro2-984fd110d6c25c2b -L dependency=/home/rodrigosilva/git/serde-test/target/debug/deps --cap-lints warn`
     Running `/home/rodrigosilva/git/serde-test/target/debug/build/proc-macro2-984fd110d6c25c2b/build-script-build`
error: failed to run custom build command for `proc-macro2 v1.0.69`

Caused by:
  could not execute process `/home/rodrigosilva/git/serde-test/target/debug/build/proc-macro2-984fd110d6c25c2b/build-script-build` (never executed)

Caused by:
  No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

I created a new project from scratch: `new folder`, `cargo init`, `cargo add serde` and then `cargo build`. In this completely isolated environment I expected that it'd build without any errors.

Comment: worked for me (linux/amd64)

Comment: `cargo clean` then try again. This should not be happening. What OS are you running?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo: I performed a `cargo clean` and got the same error. 

My SOS is:
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename: jammy

Kernel: 6.2.0-34-generic
cargo 1.73.0 (9c4383fb5 2023-08-26)
rustc 1.73.0 (cc66ad468 2023-10-03)

rustup 1.26.0 (5af9b9484 2023-04-05)
info: This is the version for the rustup toolchain manager, not the rustc compiler.
info: The currently active `rustc` version is `rustc 1.73.0 (cc66ad468 2023-10-03)`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I really don't think that the problem is related to the Serde release or Cargo. I think it is something related to my environment but I was not able to pinpoint it.

Comment: Is your `/home/rodrigosilva` mabye on a special filesystem? Or are you running some security isolation software? You could try `$ CARGO_TARGET_DIR=/tmp/foo cargo build` to put the output into a different folder/filesystem.

Comment: @Caesar, it's not in a special filesystem. It's a `ext4` mounted on "/". I don't have any special configuration for my user folder. I've also tried using CARGO_TARGET_DIR env var and I got the same error. :(

`could not execute process `/tmp/foo/debug/build/serde-fe4ad0fffe773190/build-script-build` (never executed)`

Comment: I'm not sure where to go from here.Does the file it's trying to execute (`…/proc-macro2-…./build-script-build`) actually exist? If it does, what's the output of `ldd` and `file` on it?